# Getting undefined index on PHP page when passing Variables to text in new form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this PHP Script just after my head and use it to load the info from a form on the previous page and into a form on my current page:

```
<?php

$addy = $_POST["addy"];
$imgchan = $_POST["imgchan"];
$textcol = $_POST["textcol"];
$texfont = $_POST["texfont"];
$motifsel = $_POST["motifsel"];
$motifcol = $_POST["motifcol"];
$postad = $_POST["postad"];
$emailad= $_POST["emailad"];
$custnme1= $_POST["custnme1"];
$amnt= $_POST["amnt"];
$waxs= $_POST["waxy"];
$adhel= $_POST["adhesy"];
$mult = $_POST["mult"];
$waxmul= $waxs * 1.50;
$adhemul= $adhel * 1.20;
$finalfig= $waxmul + $adhemul + $mult;

?>
```

I pass them using "php echo htmlspecialchars($finalfig)" as the value in the form and can see it puts them in the form fine

When I then click confirm on the form it shows undefined index's for the first form even though I am not passing that form to the next page. Effectively that PHP script has served its purpose and I don't understand why it is refereeing to it again.

Help!

Here is a link to the full page incase its needed

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvtgumysypdn2k9/FinalOrder.php?dl=0

```
<div style = "position: absolute; left: 180px; top: 730px;" >
<form action="testing.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="mult" id="mult" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($mult); ?>"     maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="addy" id="addy"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($addy); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="imgchan" id="imgchan"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgchan); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="textcol" id="textcol"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($textcol); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="texfont" id="texfont"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($texfont); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="motifsel" id="motifsel"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($motifsel); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="motifcol" id="motifcol" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($motifcol); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="postad" id="postad" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($postad); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="emailad" id="emailad"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($emailad); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="custnme1" id="custnme1"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($custnme1); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="amnt" id="amnt"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($amnt); ?>" maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="waxy" id="waxy"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($waxs); ?>"  maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="adhemul" id="adhemul"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($adhemul); ?>"  maxlength="62">
<input type="text" name="finalfig" id="finalfig"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($finalfig); ?>"  maxlength="62">
<div><textarea name="giftmess"cols="60" rows="8"></textarea></div>


<input type="submit" value="Confirm Your Order.">
```

And the php I am submitting to!

```
<?php

 $filename='DC_'.date('d-m-Y'). ' ' . date("h.i.sa");



$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$addy = $_POST["addy1"];
$txt = $addy;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);


 $txt = ", ";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);


 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $textcol = $_POST["textcol1"];
 $txt = $textcol;
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);


 $txt = ", ";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);


 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $texfont = $_POST["texfont1"];
 $txt = $texfont;
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);



 $txt = ", ";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);


 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $motifsel = $_POST["motifsel1"];
 $txt = $motifsel;
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);



$txt = ", ";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);


$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$motifcol = $_POST["motifcol1"];
$txt = $motifcol;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);




$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$imgchan = $_POST["imgchan1"];
$txt = $imgchan;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);



 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $postad = $_POST["postad1"];
 $txt = $postad;
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);


 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$custnme1 = $_POST["custnme11"];
$txt = $custnme1;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$amnt = $_POST["amnt1"];
$txt = $amnt;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$emailad = $_POST["emailad1"];
$txt = $emailad;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);


$txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$waxy= $_POST["waxy1"];
$txt = $waxy;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);


$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$adhemul= $_POST["adhemul1"];
$txt = $adhemul;
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);


$txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$finalfig= $_POST["finalfig1"];
 $txt = $finalfig;
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $txt = "'";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);



$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$giftmess= $_POST["giftmess1"];
$txt = $giftmess;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "'";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);



$txt = ", ";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);




fclose($myfile);
?>
Thank you for your submission!
```

Comment: until the form is submitted, none of those values will exist in $_POST. You need to check if your form is submitted first and probably set default values in the variables if the form hasn't been submitted yet.

Comment: the form is submitted by press of button so should submit fine. I have added the html form if that helps :-)

Comment: If the problem occurs only after you submit, it sounds like you should be showing us code from testing.php, not FinalOrder.php.

Comment: Fair point craigmc !

Answer (score 0):

Notice errors are not fatal, nor critical, but inform you of potential hidden bugs and encourage more secure coding (which means in this case *more code*).

You can adjust PHP's error_reporting level to dismiss them.

Quite possibly the problem is in the last section.  If you are calling htmlspecialchars($blank_variable) [and you are] you will certainly receive this error message.

You might want to do this just above the form:

```
if (isset($mult)) $mult = htmlspecialchars($mult); //do this for all variables
?>

<div style = "position: absolute; left: 180px; top: 730px;" >
<form action="testing.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="mult" id="mult" value="<?php echo $mult; ?>" maxlength="62">
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to carry out the action of the next php page so should I assume these normally fatal errors are being fatal?

Answer (score 0):

Your input names don’t match your $_POST array indexes. For instance, you use

```
name=“addy”
```

In the FinalOrder.php, but

```
$addy = $_POST[“addy1”];
```

in testing.php. They should both be either “addy” or “addy1”.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is absolutely ridiculous! It was a stray  left above the form I was submitting which was confusing it.

Many Thanks for all your help I gained some useful information from you all!